# flattening JSON file using json_normalise and choosing specific elements to convert to an excel sheet (Sample Attached)

Tags: python, json, excel, pandas, xlsx

```
{
  "currency": {
    "Wpn": {
      "units": "KB_per_sec",
      "type": "scalar", 
      "value": 528922.0, 
      "direction": "up"
  }
}, 
  "catalyst": {
    "Wpn": {
      "units": "ns", 
      "type": "scalar", 
      "value": 70144.0, 
      "direction": "down"
  }
}, 
  "common": {
    "Wpn": {
      "units": "ns", 
      "type": "scalar", 
      "value": 90624.0, 
      "direction": "down"
  }
 }
}
```

So I have to basically convert nested json into excel, for which my approach was to flatten json file using json_normalise , but as I am new to all these...I always seem to end up in KeyError...

Here's my code so far , assuming that the file is named as json.json

```py
import requests

from pandas import json_normalize

with open('json.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

df = pd.DataFrame(sum([i[['Wpn'], ['value']] for i in data], []))

df.to_excel('Ai.xlsx')
```

I'm trying to get output on an excel sheet [consisting of currency and common along with their resp. values as an output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SKUl.jpg)

I know , there are alot of similar questions , but trust me I have tried most of them and yet I didn't get any desirable output... Plz just help me in this

Comment: Please provide the key error you are seeing.

Comment: @Spectrem well i was getting: TypeError: string indices must be integers  but now it got solved...

Comment: What I meant by my comment was to add the type error to your question post so others will have more cohesive details. By providing these types of details you increase your likelihood of your question being answered and you support the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
import json
import pandas as pd

with open('json.json', 'r') as f: data = json.load(f)


data = [{'key': k, 'wpn_value': v['Wpn']['value']} for k, v in data.items()]
print(data)
# here, the variable data looks like
# [{'key': 'currency', 'wpn_value': 528922.0}, {'key': 'catalyst', 'wpn_value': 70144.0}, {'key': 'common', 'wpn_value': 90624.0}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index('key') # set_index() optional
df.to_excel('Ai.xlsx')
```

The result looks like

| key | wpn_value |
| --- | --- |
| currency | 528922 |
| catalyst | 70144 |
| common | 90624 |

Comment: Thanks man... It worked ...but what if i want to choose that only currency and common should be there or catalyst or common should be there in excel...can we have that kind of output, if possible?

Comment: You can use `data = [{'key': k, 'wpn_value': v['Wpn']['value']} for k, v in data.items() if k in ['currency', 'common']]` instead in that case.

Comment: also if I have another json file where everything is same just the Wpn_values are different , could that be added into the same excel file ?